# Npm ERR! code EPERM

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm using node v6.11.2, npm v5.3.0 and angular/cli v1.2.7.

I'm suddenly receiving the following error message for a majority of my npm installs. Never seen it before...

```
mmeppiel@MC-LT-MMEPPIEL MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Angular Solutions/my-app (master)
$ npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 font-awesome
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mmeppiel\Desktop\Angular Solutions\my-app\node_modules\fs                            events\node_modules
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\mmeppiel\Desktop                            \Angular Solutions\my-app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\mmeppiel\Desk                            top\Angular Solutions\my-app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'C:\\Users\\mme                            ppiel\\Desktop\\Angular Solutions\\my-app\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\                            '\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\mmeppiel\\Desktop\\Angular Solutions\\my-app\\node_                            modules\\fsevents\\node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mmeppiel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-08T00_56_                            59_442Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? Things I've tried:

- Running Git Bash as an administrator
- Turning off my firewall and AntiVirus protections
- Running npm cache clean
- Manually deleting the contest of AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
- Uninstalling node via the Control Panel and reinstalling
- Gave Everyone full permissions to C:\Program Files\nodejs
- Reinstalled the CLI
- Restarted my computer (can't hurt?)
- Made sure the node_modules folder is not read only

Appreciate your time!

Comment: can you `npm install` on the newly created cli project? Did you try to create app on a different path and run `npm install` on that?

Comment: npm install works as expected on the newly created CLI project. I did the same process on a different path and everything worked up until I ran npm install bootstrap --save.

Comment: That is wired. I just have `node 7.8` and `npm 5.3` running `windows 7` and just cant replicate your issue. Only two things I can think of is to try another more higher node version, if wont work, try `yarn`. BTW have you tried to look in to this one https://alastaircrabtree.com/fixing-intermittant-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-npm-install/ ?

Comment: The command lstat shouldn't be available on Windows (see this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085761/what-is-lstat-alternative-in-windows)). What about the logfile mentioned at the end of the npm err?

Comment: Thank you Kuncevic! Following the steps in the link that you provided did the trick!

Comment: Never mind...npm install mongoose --save worked immediately after I followed the instructions in that link. My second npm install failed with the same EPERM message.

Comment: Myonara, the log file has the same information as the command line output.

Comment: npm 5 is still buggy, try downgrading to npm4. Also I'd advice not using node on windows, it is designed for linux environment and works better on linux. You can use virtual machines (for example, with vagrant).

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/common-errors It's a permissions thing. You might want to look at nvm too. https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md Had you been on a Mac I'd have probably advised using Homebrew to install. Not sure how well Homebrew and Gitbash play together.

Comment: @MatthewMeppiel any luck on that? I just updated my answer if you are still didn't resolve this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using any private or company registry. check your `.npmrc` file and make sure its available.

if you are in company environment, make sure proxy is not a problem.

check in your folder if any package-lock.json is generated. you can delete that make re install.

I have little doubt but node 6.x.x with npm 5.x.x might be a problem as node 7.x.x is compatible arable with 5.x.x. And normally node 6.x.x is compatible with npm 4.x.x

Comment: Thank you Aniruddha. I deleted my package-lock.json file, reinstalled everything and there issue is gone. 

I've never seen package-lock.json before. What generated that and why was it there?

Comment: Actually node 7.x.x above is generating `package-lock.json` to hold and save your dependencies version and lock it I think. they have a document for this but I never gone in detail.

Comment: thanks @Aniruddha. I using the private registry (`verdaccio`) and I have the same problem. where id the `.npmrc` file location?

Comment: normally its in your root folder. like Users/{username} , similar in windows

Answer (score 25):

I get this error when running Visual Studio Code because the typescript compiler watches files and locks them (see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28593). The solution is to temporarily close VS Code when dealing with NPM. Perhaps you have something watching files?

Comment: If I restart my machine, immediately opened the command prompt and install anything I get the error.

Comment: I've had similar problem. Seems Parcel locked files in the project.

Answer (score 10):

I'm having the same problem, even using `Node v8.6.0` and `npm v5.4.2`.

Solved with:

`npm cache clean --force`

&

`npm install [package] --force`

Reference: [npm wiki's troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-clearing-the-npm-cache).

Answer (score 3):

This might help https://alastaircrabtree.com/fixing-intermittant-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-npm-install/

Also try to play with different `node` versions the best way of upgrading/switching your `node` on Windows is to use [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) this way you can have multiple node versions installed on your dev machine you can switch across.

#### UPDATE 0:

When you dealing with such a problems you have to make sure that nothing is locking our `node_modules` folder like your Code Editor(e.g VS Code, ect) or you might be running `npm start` in another console window, etc

#### UPDATE 1:

If you still experiencing the issue try completely to [uninstall both node and npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) from your system. Then restart your machine and install node and npm again.

#### HOWEVER

It is seams like it is common issue by looking in to the [npm issues filtering by `npm ERR! code EPERM`](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=npm%20ERR!%20code%20EPERM). If you browse some of these issues you will see that some people saying that switching the node version is actually help(exactly I was saying at first above) so you need to play with [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and see what node version is working best for you.

Once you have [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) installed you can do:

- `nvm list` - shows all your local node versions you can switch to
- `nvm list available` - shows [all actual node versions](https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json) that you can install locally
- `nvm install <version number>` - install(download+install) a particular node version
- `nvm use <version number>` switch to particular node version
- `nvm help` - will give you help

> If you jump from major version of npm some of your packages that you
>   installed with a previous node version might no longer work so you
>   have to be reinstall them

Comment: This is happening when the node command prompt is the only thing running. I've also tried upgrading to high and lower versions of node, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @MatthewMeppiel did you check this issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826 ?

Answer (score 1):

Run windows command prompt as administrator.
Then navigate ("cd directoryName")to your project folder do "npm install".

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by installing typescript globally.
The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.3.0 
Changed the version in the package.json to the installed version.
Then did an npm install

```
    npm install -g typescript
    npm info typescript version
    npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using the VS CODE Terminal, you can open cmd, or bash as administrator or root and then just `npm install (your package)`

Answer (score 0):

Very similar problem, only the specific complaint was that scandir was failing on a certain subfolder (fsevents) in the new app's target directory.  I checked and found that the folder in question did not even exist because it was the product of an optional dependency which was skipped on npm install because I was on Windows and not Linux.

The script running the app build command runs in such a way to compensate for this when "ng new " is run under Windows PowerShell.  It does not work when run in an ordinary cmd window.  So in my case the fix was simply to run "ng new  under Windows PowerShell instead of in a cmd window and the install completed successfully -- finally, after having tried several other things.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we assume that "tns run android" command will also setup the android plateform, which failed for me two times and then I resolved it by running the following two commands in the given order:

```
   tns platform add android
   tns run android
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running command prompt as administrator. Worked for me.

Comment: the same answer has been given before.

Answer (score 0):

Usually its because of no permission to access the folders inside C:/Users/...
If you have created your project in the C:/Users/.. folder, you need to get administrative permission to make changes to that folder. 
**Run your Code Editor As Administrator.** 
This will allow the program to make changes to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION SPECIFIC FOR ANGULAR APPLICATION

`Turn off your angular compiler (ie. ng serve) & again try to install the package`

Works for me every time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I went to install the react-rating package. I just switched from npm to yarn and it was solved.

That means instead of
npm install --save react-rating
I used
yarn add react-rating

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're on the incorrect version of node for your operating system. It's trying to fetch lstat (a POSIX syscall) which doesn't exist on Windows.

Currently I do not have a solution other than `install the correct npm`

Hopefully this helped you !

https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat

**EDIT**
If you can't find a fix i'd suggest for you to go to the Github Issue page.

Answer (score -1):

It might be the most basic solution, but an EPERM error can be resolved only by giving permission.

1. **Deactivate** any anti-virus software (until complete install) that there are on your PC.
2. Make sure that the **adb.exe** file (if there is) is not running on the background.

   To do this, open the task manager, go to the 'Processes' tab and end the adb.exe process.
3. **Uninstall** incomplete previous installs of expo-cli by running the command

   *npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save*
4. Now, **install** the expo-cli app

   *npm install -g expo-cli*

This has done the trick in my case. Might do for somebody else as well.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Delete node modules and run `npm cache clean --force`

Then run,

`npm install --save`

Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I delete the package-lock.json and rerun npm install again. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I tried every method listed here, but nothing seemed to work. So I uninstalled that was installed from the Windows Control Panel's Add/Remove Programs list then installed with the new version of node