# Error While creating react app by create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\SHOBHIT~1\AppData\Local
npm ERR! errno EPERM
npm ERR! FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\SHOBHIT~1\AppData\Local'
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:162:15
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1061:19)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:930:11)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:216:7)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 1)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:149:5)
npm ERR!     at async Install.install (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:170:5)
npm ERR!  FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\SHOBHIT~1\AppData\Local'

npm ERR!     at C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:162:15

npm ERR!     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1061:19)

npm ERR!     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:930:11)

npm ERR!     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:216:7)

npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 1)

npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:149:5)

npm ERR!     at async Install.install (C:\Users\SHOBHIT RAJ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:170:5) {

npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!   errno: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',

npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Users\SHOBHIT~1\AppData\Local',

npm ERR!   type: 'system',

npm ERR!   requiredBy: '.'

npm ERR! }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),

npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm ERR! code EPERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557788/npm-err-code-eperm)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

go to C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm and delete
create-react-app.ps1
create-react-app.cmd
create-react-app
node_modules/create-react-app

delete all this

and reinstall create-react-app `npm i -g create-react-app` maybe that works

Comment: this one doesn't work for me. Any other solution.