I have problem with npm, can't install anything
npm error code EPERM
npm error syscall mkdir
npm error path D:\npm-cache\_cacache
npm error errno EPERM
npm error FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@cypress%2freact: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\npm-cache\_cacache'
npm error     at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:170:15
npm error     at async Response.json (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:75:17)
npm error     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:98:25)
npm error     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:129:23)
npm error     at async #nodeFromEdge (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1055:19)npm error 
    at async #buildDepStep (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:923:11)
npm error     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:203:7)  
npm error     at async Promise.all (index 1)
npm error     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:131:5)
npm error     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.4\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:150:5) {
npm error   code: 'EPERM',
npm error   errno: 'EPERM',
npm error   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm error   path: 'D:\\npm-cache\\_cacache',
npm error   type: 'system',
npm error   requiredBy: '.'
npm error }
npm error
npm error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm error or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm error
npm error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm error the command again as root/Administrator.

npm error Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: D:\npm-cache\_logs
npm error You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal

I tried do it as administrator in PowerShell but it doesn't work.

Check this answer, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557788/npm-err-code-eperm
