# What are the consequences of git config core.filemode false?

Tags: git, cygwin

For context, I'm experiencing this and trying to solve it: [Git in Visual studio code says file is modified even when there is no change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724723/git-in-visual-studio-code-says-file-is-modified-even-when-there-is-no-change) I am using cygwin on a Windows 10 machine, but all my coworkers are using macs.

The highest voted answer says to `git config core.filemode false`, but I can't figure out the consequences of doing that. Is it safe? Does it mean if I create a shell script, pushing it will lose the executable bit? Does it mean when I pull a new executable, it will lose the executable bit? What are the gotchas, if any?

I've [checked the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), but it doesn't answer that question either, it just explains when you'd need to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that git only cares about the executable bit, so a file in git could only be 644 or 755. [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ddb1055343948e0d0bc81f8d20245f1ada6430a0/cache.h#L249)

I've just done a test:

```sh
$ mkdir test && cd test && git init
$ touch before && chmod a+x before && git add before && git commit -m 'before' && git ls-tree HEAD

> [master (root-commit) 1cb9c41] before
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 before
100755 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    before

$ git config core.fileMode false

$ touch after && chmod a+x after && git add after && git commit -m 'after' && git ls-tree HEAD

> [master b4d7a48] after
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 after
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    after
100755 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    before
```

As you can see, before the `core.fileMode` change, git keeps the file's executable bit(0755), while after the change, newly created files lost the executable bit(0644), while old files keep the old executable bit.

So, in summary:

With `git config core.filemode false`, git ignores the executable bit change on the local repository. Since git only cares about the executable bit, this won't lead to a 0000 file, but a 0644 file.

> Does it mean if I create a shell script, pushing it will lose the executable bit?

Yes

> Does it mean when I pull a new executable, it will lose the executable bit?

It depends on your file system. Some file systems such as NTFS change every files' permission to 0777 while others may lose the executable bit.

Answer (score 20):

#### TL;DR

Setting `core.filemode` to `false` makes Git ignore the executable bit of `st_mode` `lstat()` results on files in your working tree.  Instead, the mode of any existing index (staging area) entry is retained, unless you use `git update-index --chmod`.  New file index entries get mode `100644`.  This is sensible primarily when the `lstat()` emulation on your own system does not support modes correctly.

#### Long

It's generally wrong to *change* any of the `core.*` settings, including `core.fileMode` (or `core.filemode`—the documentation is not consistent about whether to give it an uppercase `M`, but in fact it does not matter anyway).  There are some special cases where you can set it manually, and here your question is the right one: *What, precisely, does this do?*

To answer that, we have to start with what "file modes" are in the first place, and how Git determines them.  A *file mode*, in Git, is really "+x" or "-x" on a committed or to-be-committed *blob object*, i.e., ordinary file.  In Git, files—or rather, file *contents*—are stored in commits as these "blob object" things: compressed, de-duplicated, and all-around-read-only, found by hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  But this is just the file's *data*, not its +x or -x state, so where does that come from?

Well, if we run `git ls-files --stage` and look at some files that are and are not executable, we find that the ones that *aren't* executable are shown as:

```
100644 <hash> 0       <name>
```

while the ones that *are* executable are shown as:

```
100755 <hash> 0       <name>
```

That `100644` or `100755` is the `mode`.  It's stored in a Git *tree object*, which Git builds at the time we run `git commit` (though we can build some earlier using `git write-tree`).  The tree object stores both the file's name and this mode, just like the index / staging-area does.<sup>2</sup>  (The index, or staging area, is what `git ls-files --stage` displays.)

So, the modes are `100644` = `-x` and `100755` = `+x`.  That leaves us with another mystery: why are they these weird numbers?  This is where the *how does Git determine these* question comes in.

Since Git was originally written for Linux and other Unix-like systems, Git depends heavily on [the `lstat` system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat).  Some other non-Unix systems don't have this as an actual *system call*, but most at least *fake* it in some sort of compatibility library.  (See, e.g., [What is lstat() alternative in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12085761/1256452))  The Unix `stat` family of calls fill in a `struct stat` in C, and this structure contains a field, `st_mode`.  The `st_mode` field is composed of various composable bits:

- Permissions: these are the lowest three octal digits.  A file that's `rw-r--r--` has `644` in these bits.  A file that's `rwxr-xr-x` has `755` in these bits.
- Three bits that don't apply to Git: these occupy the next higher octal digit.  Since they don't apply to Git, we get a zero here, always (if the OS provides a nonzero value, Git just masks it away).  That is, we'll see `0644` or `0755`, for instance, once we include the bottom three octal digits.
- "format" bits (`S_IFMT`), in the first few octal digits (e.g., the `10` or `04` in `10xxxx` or `04xxxx`): these determine whether the entity is a *file*, a *directory*, a *symbolic link*, and various other inapplicable cases.  A directory has bits `04` in this field, and a regular file has bits `10` in this field.  So a directory, after masking with these bits, winds up being `mode 040xxx`, for some permission bits `xxx`.  A file winds up being mode `100xxx`, for some permissions bits `xxx`.

When we combine these, we see two of those modes that Git shows: `100755` for an executable file, and `100644` for a non-executable regular file.  Of course a directory's `st_mode` will be `040755` or `040700` or some such, but Git doesn't bother with read/write/execute bits on *directories*, so it just masks them away: here, we see the third mode that Git shows, `040000` for tree objects linked to another tree object.<sup>4</sup>  This is also the source for the `symlink` entry mode of `120000`: the `S_IFMT` bits here are `12` on Linux and Unix.  The `commit` or *gitlink* entry type, `160000`, does not correspond to any Linux/Unix mode, but is the bitwise result of OR-ing together the `S_IFDIR` and `S_IFLNK` mode bits (`120000|040000`).

So this is where all the mode entries in the index come from: they're straight out of the `st_mode` field of a `struct stat`, as filled-in by `lstat`, with the following changes:

- For a tree object, permissions are irrelevant and are zeroed out.  (Tree objects do not appear in the index in the first place; they're created on demand by `git write-tree` when a file name requires one.)  The same holds for symlinks—where on Unix-like system the permission bits are generally ignored—and for gitlinks (which are internal to Git anyway).
- For a file, the user, group, and other read and write bits are pretended to be `rw-r--r--` always, regardless of the actual mode of the underlying file.  The presence of an `x` bit causes all three `x` bits to be set in the index mode.<sup>5</sup>

This accommodates historical mistakes (see footnote 5) and is therefore somewhat messy.  It would be much simpler if the storage format simply held the file type and, for files, `+x` or `-x`, for instance, but it does also leave room for future expansion (e.g., the entire setuid+setgid+sticky set of 3 bits is currently always zero, so nonzero values could acquire meanings).

**All of this makes sense in a Unix-like environment, where the mode bits are preserved in ordinary on-disk files.**  But in other systems, the `lstat` mode bits are literally faked.  Windows is the canonical example here.  There is no "executable bit", so `lstat`-ing a file on Windows must either show all files as executable, or no files as executable, if we're to make up an arbitrary `x` bit result.

Hence, when you run `git init` to create a *new repository*, Git probes the system's underlying behavior.  Git creates a file with an OS "create new file" call (`open(name, O_CREAT|other_open_flags, mode)`) with mode 0644.  It then tries using an OS `chmod` call to change the mode to 0755, and then uses an OS `lstat` call to see if the change "sticks".<sup>6</sup>  If so, the OS must honor `x` bits, so Git will set `core.filemode` to `true`.  If not, the OS must disregard `x` bits, so Git will set `core.filemode` to `false`.

Later, if `core.filemode` is *false*, Git will call `lstat` as usual to get stat data for each file, but will *completely ignore* the three `x` bits in the `st_mode` result.  It will read the existing index entry for that file to get the `x` bits to set in any new updated index entry for that file.  The one exception to this rule is the `git update-index` operation, where the user can specify an entire mode, or use the `--chmod` flag:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x path/to/file.ext
```

This grabs the existing index entry, checks that it's for a file (`mode 100xxx`), and if so, replaces the `xxx` part with `755`: the file is now marked `+x`.  Similarly, `--chmod=-x` replaces the `xxx` part with `644` (again only for regular files; you cannot `--chmod` a symlink or gitlink).

If `core.filemode` is *true*, however, any ordinary `git add` on a file will read and obey the working tree's `x` bits.  If `lstat` has `st_mode` set to `100700`, for instance, the index entry will become `100755`.  If `lstat` has `st_mode` set to `100444`, the index entry becomes `100644`.

That is, in C-like code that doesn't quite match the internals of Git, the new mode, for any ordinary file, is:

```
ce = lookup_existing_cache_entry(path);
if (core_filemode) {
    // Note: the link in banyudu's answer goes to code
    // that checks `& 0100`, not `& 0111`.  Perhaps Git
    // only inspects the user's bit.
    new_mode = st.st_mode & 0111 ? 100755 : 100644;
} else {
    new_mode = ce != NULL && ce->ce_mode == 100755 ? 100755 : 100644;
}
```

Once the file is added, the cache entry (index) `mode` field is set to `new_mode`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The hash ID of the blob object is determined strictly by the contents: it's a checksum of the data prefixed by the word `blob`, an ASCII space (0x20), the data size in bytes expressed in decimal, and an ASCII NUL (0x00) byte.  The checksum function is currently SHA-1 although an upcoming Git change will start using SHA-256.  This hashing is in fact how the de-duplication works: given the same byte sequence, Git produces the same hash ID.  So if the literal text `hello world` plus a newline <kbd>CTRL-J</kbd> byte is stored in Git as a blob object, using SHA-1, we have:

```
$ printf 'blob 12\0hello world\n' | shasum
3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad  -
```

so we see that every file containing just the one line `hello world` has blob hash ID `3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad`, in *every Git repository everywhere*.  Try it:

```
$ echo 'hello world' > hello.txt
$ git add hello.txt
$ git ls-files --stage hello.txt
100644 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad 0       hello.txt
```

Note the blob hash ID, `3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad`, is just what we calculated it would be.

<sup>2</sup>There are some important differences between *tree* entries and *index* entries.  In particular, an index entry has the file's full name spelled out complete with forward slashes, so that, e.g., file `path/to/file.ext` is just that: `path/to/file.ext` in the index.<sup>3</sup>  But as a set of tree objects, Git breaks this up into pseudo-directories, so that we have `path`, `to`, and `file.ext`.  The `path` part is stored in the top level tree of the commit; the `to` part is stored as a subtree of the `path` tree; and the `file.ext` part is stored as a blob entry in the `to` tree.  The top level tree has a subtree entry named `path` that holds the hash ID of the subtree that holds the name `to` and the hash ID of the subtree that holds the name `file.ext`.  (Whew!)  This is easier seen by working from the bottom up, recursively:

- We build a tree at the bottom level holding `100644 file.ext` and any other names under the `to` name.  We store this tree object in the objects database, finding its internal hash ID.
- Now we build another tree holding `40000 to` and the hash ID of the tree we just built, along with any other entries needed to go under `path`.
- Finally, we build a tree holding `40000 path` and the hash ID of the tree we built in the middle step, plus any other entries needed to go in the top level.

This set of trees is what `git write-tree` builds, using whatever is in Git's index at this time.  The `git write-tree` program then emits the hash ID of the top level tree, which is what goes into the commit object that `git commit-tree` builds.

<sup>3</sup>The current index format uses compression tricks to avoid repeating leading strings.  See the [technical documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt) for details.

<sup>4</sup>The leading zero is stripped in the modes stored in the `tree` object, but re-inserted for display purposes in `git ls-tree -r` output, for instance.

<sup>5</sup>In very early versions of Git, more mode bits were preserved into the Git `mode` field.  This turned out to be a mistake.  Today, for backwards compatibility, Git *allows* an existing `mode` of `100664` (`rw-rw-r--`), but will never create any *new* ones, so that existing Git repositories that date back to this early version of Git can be read.

<sup>6</sup>If I remember right, the actual test consists of: stat the file, flip *all* the X bits (`new_mode = old_mode ^ 0111`), chmod, stat again, and see if the result changed.  If so, at least one X bit is obeyed.  If not, no X bit is obeyed.

Comment: `in the octal digits above these last four octal digits` it's hard for me to understand what this sentence means. Can you word it differently?

Comment: That's already a second or third attempt, but I'll try :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I learned a lot

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Windows and Linux have different permissions models. Git uses the Linux model internally.

On Windows, `git config core.filemode false` tells Git to not consider file permissions when determining if a file has changed.

Comment: Elaborating on what it means to "not consider file permissions" is the main question I'm asking.